# Return certain type from generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, mono

I am having question about generic method.

Let's say i am creating a game with custom UI, and it has `ResourceManager` class.
There is method to get the object from the `ResourceManager` and its returning a generic type, here is the class code:

```
public class ResourceManager
{
        // The list that store the object
        private List<Control> _objects = new List<Control>();

        // Add object into the list
        public void Add(params Control[] objects)
        {
            _objects.AddRange(objects);
        }

        // Get the object from the list
        public T GetObject<T>(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Control obj in _objects)
                {
                    if (obj.Name == name)
                        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return default(T);
        }
}
```

as you can see, the Objects is `Control` class.
In my project, there is few classes that inherit this class, Let's say its `Button` , `Image` and `CheckBox`

The code run smoothly when i call:

```
CheckBox checkBox = ResourceManager.GetObject<CheckBox>("CheckBox1");
Control control = ResourceManager.GetObject<Control>("Control1");
```

The problem is, its accepting any type, like:

```
string str = ResourceManager.GetObject<string>("blablabla1");
int num = ResourceManager.GetObject<int>("blablabla2");
```

I just want the code wont compile when the type is not `Control` and the inheritance of it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a constraint `public T GetObject<T>(string name) where T:Control`

Comment: Never heard about `where` statement in C# , Thanks!

Comment: @ChronoCross Look up Generic Type Constraints